# How to call a function within a function also passing $(this) object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example of code what I am trying to do.

This is not working:

```
function fnSelectableDiv(){
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  $(this).addClass('selected-div');
}

$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  fnSelectableDiv()
});
```

If i do as mentioned below, things will work but I am trying to figure out how to make above code work:

```
$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  $(this).addClass('selected-div');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.selectableDiv{width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 2px solid #333}
.selected-div{background-color:red)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectableDiv"></div>
<div class="selectableDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple ways how you can solve it

**Use `.call()` to set `this` in your function:**

```
function fnSelectableDiv(){
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  $(this).addClass('selected-div');
}

$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  fnSelectableDiv.call(this); // set context for fnSelectableDiv.
});
```

**Pass the value of `this` as an argument to this function:**

```
function fnSelectableDiv(el){
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  $(el).addClass('selected-div');
}

$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  fnSelectableDiv(this); // pass this as argument 
});
```

Comment: use `.call($(this))` instead... as this.addClass() won't work but $(this).addClass() works...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - why?  There's no advantage to passing `$(this)` instead of passing `this`.  In fact, your method makes more work for the caller and less common code in the function.

Comment: will this.addClass() work then?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - I don't know what you're asking.  This answer does not use `this.addClass()` anywhere.  It uses either `$(this).addClass()` or `$(el).addClass()` - both of which will work in their context.

Answer (score 1):

**Pass the arguement to 'fnSelectableDiv(obj)'**

```
function fnSelectableDiv(obj){
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  $(obj).addClass('selected-div');
}

$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  fnSelectableDiv(this); // pass this as argument 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
function fnSelectableDiv(elem){//pass a parameter for element
  $('.selectableDiv').removeClass('selected-div');
  elem.addClass('selected-div');
}

$('.selectableDiv').click(function () {
  fnSelectableDiv($(this))//use element as $(this)
});
```